# Spring parent-child project setup

Tags: spring, maven

I'm trying to create a parent-child project using spring and maven with no luck. I found many examples but all refeers to multi-module project.

What I have is a core project that need to be imported to many others child project.
The core project have some dependencies and those have to be inherited to the childs.

I tried to convert the core project as multi module, with no luck. This is my configuration.

**core-project pom.xml** (this have a module)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>it.mygroup</groupId>
    <artifactId>core-be</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
    <name>core-be</name>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>

    <modules>
        <module>backend</module>
    </modules>

</project>
```

Next to this i have the module backend, that define spring boot configuration and so on.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.0</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <groupId>it.mygroup</groupId>
    <artifactId>backend</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
    <name>backend</name>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

This is the core project that need to be imported to any other projects. I tried to import this as parent, but all the classes defined in the core project are not found:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>it.mygroup</groupId>
        <artifactId>core-be</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0</version>
    </parent>
    <groupId>it.mygroup</groupId>
    <artifactId>my-project</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>my-project</name>
    
    <build>
        <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
    </build>

</project>
```

Comment: The `core-project pom` is useless as there is no configuration inside it so nothing will be inherited to other childs apart from the version !

Comment: I know, this was just a try to see if for some reason that was the problem :( I tried the same configuration without using the parent as packaging pom but i got always the same error.. the classes in the child project are not found.. But is better to create a parent-child configuration, or just use the core project in the child as recular dependency ?

Comment: Try to add the project `core-be` a dependency with the coordinates `backend`.if you are using it.

Comment: Using the core project as regular dependency works because is the conriguration that already i'm using. I'm asking if there is a better way (for example, inherit from another project like show above). So, is better to have the core as regular dependency ?

Comment: The only solution I can come up is to put the dependencies and configuration that will be shared in all submodules in one parent pom and provide all inherited projects in the `<modules>` section. After that all you have to do is in every pom of submodules to specify the parent already configured.

Comment: Can you please provide me a little example ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/229239/discussion-between-mistre83-and-meninx-).

Comment: Does this answer your question ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the core-project  configuation which is the parent:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.0</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <groupId>it.mygroup</groupId>
    <artifactId>core-be</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
    <name>core-be</name>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>

    <modules>
        <module>backend</module>
        <module>my-project</module>
    </modules>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

After that each project will inherit from it:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <parent>
        <groupId>it.mygroup</groupId>
        <artifactId>core-be</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0</version>
    </parent>

    <groupId>it.mygroup</groupId>
    <artifactId>backend</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
    <name>backend</name>

</project>
```

And my-project configuration:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <parent>
        <groupId>it.mygroup</groupId>
        <artifactId>core-be</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0</version>
    </parent>

    <groupId>it.mygroup</groupId>
    <artifactId>my-project</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>my-project</name>

</project>
```